# Brightcove account how to get a list of playerKey/playerID

Tags: video-player, brightcove

We are trying to provide the end user a easy way to select both a video and a player to be displayed on the final HTML page.

Is there a way to programmatically get a list of all players (playerKey/playerID/playerType) for one account?

If not, is it on the roadmap to support this functionality?

Using the Media API we've been able to get all the videos. 
But we can't seem to find a way to do the same for the players.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a way to get player information from Brightcove's API.